# validation of fields in this situation 

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="default-box">
    <span class="add"><input type="text" class="name" /><input type="text"  class="email"/></span>
    <span class="add"><input type="text" class="name" /><input type="text"  class="email"/></span>
    <span class="add"><input type="text" class="name" /><input type="text"  class="email"/></span>

</div>
```

This code will arrange the name and email fields in rows and column. First row will contain name and email as a unit and same for the other rows.
I want to validate each row as unit. Suppose name or email field are empty or email is not valid so when I enter the tab from email column of 1st row to move to second row it will show an error.
I could not figure out the way to catch a row as unit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `(JQuery)`

```
var allCorrect = true;
$('span.add').each(function(index){
    var name = $(this).children('input.name').val();
    var email = $(this).children('input.email').val();
    //VALIDATE name AND email HERE
    if (/*not-valid boolean here*/)
    {
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid red"); // Set red-border for wrong row 
        allCorrect = false;
    }
});
if(allCorrect)
{
    //DO SOMETHING ABOUT IT
}
```

You can put this in a function. Which could be called on form submit or click of button.

Comment: There is no way to know why someone downvoted the question if they don't answer themselves so please don't use flags. The moderators don't know either. Also, if you're intent on working on your reputation, you should make sure you leave good answers. This answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141557/i-need-an-analog-jquery-clockpick/6141595#6141595 - has no content beyond a link, that doesn't work. That's not the way to build reputation on SE-sites. Post *good* content.